# La diferencia entre “habrá de” y “habrá que”

Tags: significado

Quisiera preguntar si existe alguna diferencia de significado entre “habrá de” y “habrá que”. Por ejemplo, “El Parlamento Europeo habrá de desempeñar un papel en ese procedimiento“ vs. ”El Parlamento Europeo habrá que desempeñar un papel en ese procedimiento“. Muchas gracias.

Comment: En tu ejemplo veo posible 'El Parlamento Europeo habrá de desempeñar' o 'El Parlamento Europeo tendrá que desempeñar', si se quieres usar 'habrá que desempeñar' tienes que omitir el sujeto en quien recae “Habrá que desempeñar un papel en ese procedimiento“.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resumiendo y ampliando un poco:

- Fulanito HABRÁ DE / TENDRÁ QUE  hacer tal cosa --personal: la obligación o necesidad será de fulanito.
  Lo que no veo tan claro es que TENER QUE sea preferido en el habla corriente a HABER DE. En todo caso esta forma también es muy común. Más bien me parece que con TENER QUE la necesidad suena más fuerte que con HABER DE.
- HABRÁ QUE hacer tal cosa -- impersonal, forma futura de HAY QUE, será necesario hacer tal cosa, sin especificar quién habrá de hacerlo. También puede usarse TENDREMOS QUE / HABREMOS DE, o usar la pasiva refleja, con el impersonal SE: "SE TENDRÁ QUE / SE HABRÁ DE entregar antes de..." con la posibilidad de poner el SE  pegado al final del verbo principal: "TENDRÁ QUE / HABRÁ DE entregarSE antes de..."

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus detalladas explicaciones! Ahora lo entiendo todo. Saludos

Comment: Pero si se usa "HABREMOS DE", la construcción ya deja de ser impersonal, ¿no es así? Muchas gracias otra vez ~